# How can I test this script that accesses urls through several different proxy servers?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Right now this is the script:

```
import json
import urllib2  

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    urls = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
with open('proxies.txt') as proxies:
    for line in proxies:
        proxy = json.loads(line)
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        for url in urls:
            data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            print data
```

This is the urls.txt file:

```
http://myipaddress.com
```

and the proxies.txt file:

```
{"https": "https://87.98.216.22:3128"}
{"https": "http://190.153.7.189:8080"}
{"https": "http://125.39.68.181:80"}
```

that I got at http://hidemyass.com

I have been trying to test it by going through the terminal output (a bunch of html) and looking to see if it shows the ip address somewhere and hoping that it is one of the proxy ip's. But this doesn't seem to work. Depending on the ip recognition site, either it throws a connection error or tells me I have to enter validation letters (though the site viewed through the browser works fine).

So am I going about this in the best way? Is there a simpler way to check what ip address the url is seeing?

Edit: I heard elsewhere (on another forum) that one way to check if the url is being accessed from a different ip is to check for cross headers (like the html header indicates that it was redirected). But I can't find any more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simpler site like [this](http://api.exip.org/?call=ip). Example:

**Code:**

```
import json 
import urllib2

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    urls = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
with open('proxies.txt') as proxies:
    for line in proxies:
        proxy = json.loads(line)
        proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxy)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
        for url in urls:
            try:
                data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
                print proxy, "-", data 
            except:
                print proxy, "- not working"
```

**urls.txt:**

```
http://api.exip.org/?call=ip
```

**proxies.txt:**

```
{"http": "http://218.108.114.140:8080"}
{"http": "http://59.47.43.93:8080"}
{"http": "http://218.108.170.172:80"}
```

**Output:**

```
{u'http': u'http://218.108.114.140:8080'} - 218.108.114.140
{u'http': u'http://59.47.43.93:8080'} - 118.207.240.161
{u'http': u'http://218.108.170.172:80'} - not working
[Finished in 25.4s]
```

*Note: none of this is my real IP.*

Or if you want to use http://myipaddress.com you can do that with BeautifulSoup, by extracting exact HTML element which contains you IP

Comment: very useful site and useful answer